# virtualbox, не работает мышь

Tags: virtualbox

При запуске виртуальной linux-машины не захватывается мышь на большей части экрана, при этом клавиатура работает. Часть экрана, на которой нажатия мыши не работают, выделена на скрине.
Раньше все было окей, случилось с какого-то момента. Возможно, после установки в виртуальной машине обновлений системы (это не точно)

Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

VirtualBox  6.1.36, Ubuntu 22.04

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А еще, каждый раз при запуске, в системе сбрасывается настройка разрешения и приходится первым делом его менять,тоже непонятно что сделать

Comment: [guest additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/LinuxAdditionsDebug) проверьте

Comment: В одном из файлов логов ошибка, которую пока не пойму как пофиксить:

Building the main Guest Additions 6.1.36 module for kernel 5.15.0-47-generic.
Error building the module.  Build output follows.
/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-6.1.36/src/vboxguest-6.1.36/build_in_tmp: 80: make: not found

Comment: Попробуйте обновить аддишены через менеджер пакетов.  Это по сути драйвера от виртуалбокса. Так же выполните `/sbin/rcvboxadd` из под рута, посмотрите что пишет

Comment: Обновил, /sbin/rcvboxadd выводит список команд, попробовал добавить setup и update
Не помогает. Работает также периодически, если запустить ВМ 5 раз, может один из пяти будет удачно.